Unable to login to website in Chrome using Selenium Webdriver in Python
I am using Selenium module in Python to login to the website www.value,researchonline.com..
I am able to click the button that says 'login with password' and then execute the code to input the username. But when i click on the 'Submit' button, it gives an error "Unable to process your request. Please try again.". I believe this is due to the website blocking automated script for login. Code is pasted below.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Set up the Chrome WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "https://www.valueresearchonline.com/login/?site-code=VROL&amp;target=%2F&amp;utm_source=home&amp;utm_medium=vro&amp;utm_campaign=desktop-profile-menu/"
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Click the button 'Login with password' (step 1)
login_button1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-user='Log in with password']")
login_button1.click()

# Define login credentials
username = 'abc@gmail.com'
# Find the username input field and submit button (step 2)
username_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'username')
# Enter the username into the field
username_field.send_keys(username)

login_button2 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='proceed-btn']")
# Submit the username to go to the password page
login_button2.click()

I have checked some related threads on stackoverflow, but most of them didn't have a solution or the proposed solution didn't work for me. Please advise if there is any workaround.
Thanks for the help.

If the company is blocking automated scraping you should expect any work around you find to stop working withing days or weeks. Many companies offering this sort of data also provide an API, but you'd have to contact the company in question for details.

I can't comment so I am going to just use the answer...
Could you try using Undetected Chromedriver? It at least will solve the captcha when you open the website. I ran the code but I am not sure exactly what output you are looking for. If you could guide me I could try to help some more. Here is the code


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.valueresearchonline.com/login/?site-code=VROL&amp;target=%2F&amp;utm_source=home&amp;utm_medium=vro&amp;utm_campaign=desktop-profile-menu/"

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Click the button 'Login with password' (step 1)
login_button1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-user='Log in with password']")
login_button1.click()

# Define login credentials
username = 'groundbreakingminecraft@gmail.com'
# Find the username input field and submit button (step 2)
username_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'username')
# Enter the username into the field
username_field.send_keys(username)

login_button2 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='proceed-btn']")
# Submit the username to go to the password page
login_button2.click()




Thanks for the changes. this works just fine. I am able to login and see the dashboard, however the dashboard takes almost 2-3 minutes to load as against instantly when i login to the website manually. Any idea why that might be the case? Do i need to add some code to clear the cache etc.?

I am not sure sorry, but maybe take a look at this post? Good look with your scraping! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73999362/undetected-chromedriver-runs-slowly-suggestions

Thanks this link looks promising
